# Apple Pay in the South African market

Tags: ios, applepay

I want to implement Apple Pay in one of my applications. However while reading, I found a post saying that it is supported only for UK and US and not for South Africa. If I upload a build having Apple Pay functionality, will it work for South Africa? Also, is the app likely to be rejected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your own question:

> it is supported only for UK and US

> will it work for South Africa?

**No**

---

If your application is only going to be available in South Africa, then your user's simply won't be able to use Apple Pay (yet. Apple Pay may be rolled out in the future) and you should implement another solution

If the application is available worldwide, your users in the US and UK will be able to use Apple Pay, however, no others will and you should either implement a solution to replace Apple Pay, or include another option for users that can't access Apple Pay.

I think it's **unlikely** that an app would be rejected for including Apple Pay if the app is available worldwide. However, this part of your question is off topic, and I can't provide a definite answer.